# The p tag breaks a line before it is full

Tags: html, css

[image]

please see the picture and  the problem.
you can see that the p element is not full but breaks a line.
can you tell me the reason?
thanks a lot!

The code consists of three blocks, each with three text descriptions. But in the second text block, when the page pixel is less than 768px, even if a line of text is not full, it will still break the line. Right? I looked at my code and still didn't know what was wrong. I hope you can answer my questions. thank you

```css
  
            .info{
                background-color: #ffffff;
                box-shadow: #aaa9a9 5px 3px 50px ;
                margin-top: 40px;
                border-radius: 15px;
            }
            .info1_1{
                height: 350px;
            }
            .info1_2{
                float: right;
                margin-top: 40px;
            }
            .info2_1{
                height: 450px;
            }
            .info3_1{
                height: 400px;
            }
            .info p{
                color: #eb6100;
                font-size: 20px;
                margin: 0 8%;
                padding-top: 10%;
             
            }
            .info_img{
                text-align: center;
                margin: 30px auto;
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
                .info1,.info2,.info3{
                    width: 70%;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
                .col-sm-5,.col-sm-6{
                    float: none;

                }
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 640px){
                .info1,.info2,.info3{
                    width: 90%;
                }
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 500px){
                .info p{
                    font-size: 16px;
                }
            }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maxinum-scale=1.0,user-scale=no" />
  <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Hamiio technology--professional software and hardware customization</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
    <header></header>
    <div class="body">
     
        <div class="about">
           
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1"></div>
                <div class="row col-lg-11 col-md-11">
                    <div class="info1 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="info1_1 info">
                            <p>Hami technology, founded by shenzhen yicu innovation software co., LTD in 2010, is located in huizhou, guangdong, the beautiful founder of the former xunlei group of system architects, the company has a number of long-term software development professionals.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info1_2 hidden-sm"><img src="paper.png"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info2 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 ">
                        <div class="info2_1 info">
                            <p>The company's main business is: 1. Software customization development. 2.Customized development of software and hardware. Including system customization (Linux , Android , wince), software development.
                            </p>
                            <div class="info_img">
                                <img src="solution2.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 "></div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8  info3">
                    <div class="info info3_1">
                        <p>After more than 10 years of development experience, our project implementation team can more accurately make corresponding solutions according to the actual needs of customers. Hami team is a dedicated customer service team to give customers a perfect result.</p>
                        <div class="info_img">
                            <img src="img/solution1.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>**strong text**
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: do you mean the space your p tag used ?

Comment: can you create demo/jsfiddle so we can check

Comment: I could take a guess - it looks like there's a floating element on the page somewhere in the code, but if I could see the code, I wouldn't have to guess.

Comment: cant understand the problem. Please be clear so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer!
because bootstrap class "hidden-sm" just make the element's opacity to 0. So the element still taking up space.